# Superfluous curly braces

Tags: javascript, braces

I have a student who likes to wrap large sections of code in curly braces so he can collapse those sections in the code editor. Initially, I balked at it, but couldn't think of a legitimate reason not to allow him to do it. **I'm wondering if this practice will create any problems later on.**

Example:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1;

{  if (a == b){
      alert("a = b");
   }
   else if (a > b){
      alert("a > b");
   }
   else if (a < b){
      alert("a < b");
   }
}
```

I know there's a debate about braces around single statements inside an if, that's not what I'm talking about. I'm talking about the "parent" braces, if you will, around the series of if/else if statements.

Comment: *"I understand that variables declared inside braces have a limited scope"* - your understanding is wrong.

Comment: The braces don't do anything at all as far as Javascript is concerned. It's a stylistic choice only.

Comment: To expand on the above comment, JavaScript doesn't have _block_ scope; it only has _function_ scope.

Comment: .. I have this nagging feeling that said student is using `var foo = { a: 1, b: 2};`

Comment: @deceze My bad I read it in a Java posting and assumed it was applicable to C based languages. I obviously still have a lot to learn.

Comment: @tereško no, that's not it, but interesting scenario. I wonder what would happen...

Comment: @jnitram78 - That's an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543277/superfluous-curly-braces#comment39882618_25543277) indicated in his comment, you are incorrect about the braces limiting the scope of the variables.

```
var a = "outside";
{
    var a = "inside";
    var b = "another inside";
}
console.log(a); // prints "inside"
console.log(b); // prints "another inside"
```

Having said that, if you need to add in braces to make the code easier to navigate (read: ignore) it's a sign that the function is too long and should be broken apart into well named functions.

Comment: So is it correct to say that what my student was doing would have no negative impact on how his code would work? As for his function being too long, it's not even a function, it's just a loooong string of if/else if statements. I admit I have a lot to learn, and my students are only in their second week of class. This particular student is striking out on his own, but I wanted to break any bad habits before they begin.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: A long sequence of `if/else` can sometimes be refactored to something more readable/concise too. I personally wouldn't like the extra braces because it adds indentation for no benefit.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion, and I am in total agreement with you, but I'm looking for a definitive "Yes, and here's why..." or "No. and Here's why..."  I think I got "No" in @deceze's comment above, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: It doesn't do anything. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1. "The production Block : { StatementList } is evaluated as follows:

Return the result of evaluating StatementList."